# Assign a property of an object with properties of different type

Tags: typescript

This code was valid in 3.3.3, but fails to compile in 3.5.1 and newer. How can I fix it? [Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3gWAChlk4AuZAZzClAHMBuIkgIwpAFcBbF6JwgL5EiANzhRkMAPZQuFDFhwBePKQoAidQBpkbZAAZkA-kRgcQCMMCkhkAEykBlLmAAWAChjAIAGzsUAawgATykYNExsHTEfDggKOBBggEo8ZkkZLgBtL187AF1kFRi4hmQAenLkABVggAcUAHJE4MbkYEpkECkwUkpKYDoQOBYfFDApZDB6ppAIEWhGgDoiASA)

```
interface IData {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

var form: IData = { a: "", b: 0 };

function doSmth(field: keyof IData, value: any) {
  form[field] = value; // Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}
```

Ok, seems I've understood the reason: earlier type of `form[field]` was `string | number`, but now it is `string & number` which is `never`. But I still ned to make it working...

Comment: `form[field] = value as never;` 

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, seems like a very strange hack)))

Comment: [this](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/keyof-and-lookup-types-in-typescript). May go some way towards helping you.

Comment: @PaulRooney, you mean, I have to make function generic?

Comment: I don't know sorry. Not a ts expert by any means. I had a crack at it but to make it work I had to pass the object, key and value. Doesn't seem like a useful thing to do, you may as well just directly mutate the object.

Comment: @PaulRooney, yep, generics helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [solved](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3gWAChlk4AuZAZzClAHMBuIkgIwpAFcBbF6JwgL5EiANzhRkMAPZQuFDFhwBePKQoAidQBpkbZAAZkA-kRgcQCMMCkhkAEykBlLmAAWAHgBiyCAA9IIHaUyADWEACeUjBomNjIKmGR0QrYAHwAFDDAEAA2dhSeOmI5HBDysXAA2p4AugCUeMySMlyVWbl2NfHIxaX8QoREDs5u6epw2sjjLAjqdUNOLq5jLJMAjADM84RAA) by using a generic parameter:

```
interface IData {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

var form: IData = { a: "", b: 0 };

function doSmth<F extends keyof IData = keyof IData>(field: F, value: IData[F]) {
  form[field] = value;
}

doSmth("a", "abc")
doSmth("b", 13)
```